# Menu Bar Strip icon for MacOS is not showing when developing with Flutter

Tags: swift, flutter, macos, statusbar, menubar

I'm trying to render an icon in the menu bar for my MacOS app. I'm developing using  Flutter 3.10.5 and using XCode-Beta 15 Beta 3 on MacOS Sanoma.

This is my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import AppKit
import FlutterMacOS
import Cocoa

class StatusBarController {
    private var statusBar: NSStatusBar
    private var statusItem: NSStatusItem
    private var popover: NSPopover
    private var menu: NSMenu?

    init(_ popover: NSPopover) {
        self.popover = popover
        self.popover.animates = false // Disable animation for faster open/close
        statusBar = NSStatusBar.init()
        statusItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: 28.0)

        if let statusBarButton = statusItem.button {
            statusBarButton.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("mac16.png"))
            statusBarButton.image?.size = NSSize(width: 16.0, height: 16.0)
            statusBarButton.image?.isTemplate = true // Set this to false if your image has important color information
            statusBarButton.action = #selector(togglePopover(sender:))
            statusBarButton.target = self
            statusBarButton.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp])
        }

        menu = NSMenu()
        menu?.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Item 1", action: #selector(item1Action), keyEquivalent: ""))
        menu?.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Item 2", action: #selector(item2Action), keyEquivalent: ""))
        menu?.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
        menu?.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))
    }

    @objc func togglePopover(sender: AnyObject) {
        let event = NSApp.currentEvent!
        if event.type == NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp {
            statusItem.menu = menu
            statusItem.button?.performClick(nil)
            statusItem.menu = nil
        } else {
            if(popover.isShown) {
                hidePopover(sender)
            }
            else {
                showPopover(sender)
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func item1Action() {
        // Add your code for Item 1 here
    }

    @objc func item2Action() {
        // Add your code for Item 2 here
    }

    func showPopover(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let statusBarButton = statusItem.button {
            popover.show(relativeTo: statusBarButton.bounds, of: statusBarButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
        }
    }

    func hidePopover(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        popover.performClose(sender)
    }
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var popover = NSPopover()
    var statusBar: StatusBarController?
    var flutterViewController: FlutterViewController?

    override func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        flutterViewController = FlutterViewController.init()
        popover.contentViewController = flutterViewController
        popover.animates = false // Disable animation for faster open/close
        statusBar = StatusBarController(popover)
        // Pre-load the view
        _ = flutterViewController?.view
    }

    override func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

And this is my Flutter app code in main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Chef App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          bodyLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: 'Arial'),
          bodyMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: 'Arial'),
        ),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Chef App Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _response = '';
  bool _isLoading = false;
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> getFoodOption() async {
    if (_isLoading) return;

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/food'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
          'dietaryConstraint': _controller.text,
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          _response = jsonDecode(response.body)['recipe'];
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      } else {
        showErrorSnackBar('Server error: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showErrorSnackBar('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  void showErrorSnackBar(String errorMessage) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage)),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: RawKeyboardListener(
                  focusNode: FocusNode(),
                  onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
                    if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
                      getFoodOption();
                    }
                  },
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter dietary constraint',
                    ),
                    autofocus: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: _isLoading
                    ? Shimmer.fromColors(
                  baseColor: Colors.grey[700]!,
                  highlightColor: Colors.grey[500]!,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (_, __) => Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    itemCount: 20,
                  ),
                )
                    : _response.isNotEmpty
                    ? Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: SelectableText(
                      _response,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                    : Container(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getFoodOption,
        tooltip: 'Fetch',
        child: _isLoading ? const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white) : const Icon(Icons.send),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Although the AppIcon is being rendered, the status bar doesn't show anything. Surprisingly the space for the icon is created, so there's a blank space where you can left click and right click and show an instance of the app but it is not showing the icon itself.

Also, this is my asset folder structure and names:
[image]

[image]

This is my Contents.json file:

```
{
  "info": {
    "author": "xcode-app-icon-exporter",
    "version": 1
  },
  "images": [
    {
      "idiom": "ios-marketing",
      "size": "1024x1024",
      "scale": "1x",
      "filename": "appstore1024.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "20x20",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "notification40.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "20x20",
      "scale": "3x",
      "filename": "notification60.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "settings58.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "3x",
      "filename": "settings87.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "spotlight80.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "3x",
      "filename": "spotlight120.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "60x60",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "iphone120.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "size": "60x60",
      "scale": "3x",
      "filename": "iphone180.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "20x20",
      "scale": "1x",
      "filename": "ipadNotification20.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "20x20",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "ipadNotification40.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "1x",
      "filename": "ipadSettings29.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "29x29",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "ipadSettings58.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "1x",
      "filename": "ipadSpotlight40.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "40x40",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "ipadSpotlight80.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "76x76",
      "scale": "1x",
      "filename": "ipad76.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "76x76",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "ipad152.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "ipad",
      "size": "83.5x83.5",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "ipadPro167.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "mac",
      "size": "16x16",
      "scale": "1x",
      "filename": "mac16.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "mac",
      "size": "16x16",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "mac32.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "mac",
      "size": "32x32",
      "scale": "1x",
      "filename": "mac32.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "mac",
      "size": "32x32",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "mac64.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "mac",
      "size": "128x128",
      "scale": "1x",
      "filename": "mac128.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "mac",
      "size": "128x128",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "mac256.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "mac",
      "size": "256x256",
      "scale": "1x",
      "filename": "mac256.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "mac",
      "size": "256x256",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "mac512.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "mac",
      "size": "512x512",
      "scale": "1x",
      "filename": "mac512.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom": "mac",
      "size": "512x512",
      "scale": "2x",
      "filename": "mac1024.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've explained everything above, but also I've tried clearing my cache using these commands:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

This is also my pubspec.yaml if you're interested in running this:

```
name: chefapp
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.3
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  shimmer: ^2.0.0


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```